# How are SHACAL-2 ciphers calculated?

Tags: hash, block-cipher, sha-256, md5, merkle-damgaard

I am trying to learn about the underlying functionality of the different hash functions (currently SHA) and I'm pretty stuck even after watching a Stanford video about it.

One method of hashing is by using Merkel-Damgård construction with the David Meyers function and SHACAL-2 block ciphers.

As far as I understand MD is the message divided into a chain of 64-bit blocks containing the previous block value or IV (initial vector defined by the hash function or a custom salt key). The block value or IV along with the current block value and some x bit key is after going through the SHACAL-2 function then the new cipher.

Is this correct understood? If it is:
What happens inside the SHACAL function? What is math?

I found this but it doesn't really answer my question:
[SHACAL in SHA-256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18566/shacal-in-sha-256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MD construction uses a [compression function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function) $C$ ($F$ in the figures) such that it has two inputs.

$$h_i = C(h_{i-1},m_i)$$

[image]

and the first $h_{-1} = IV$ and the last $H = h_{2^k-1}$ is the hash  value.

[image]

The compression function can use a block cipher, where the message to the block cipher is the previous hash value and the key is the message. $h_i = E_{m}(h_{i-1})$

The first description of using a block cipher for compression function exists in Merkle's [thesis on page 11](http://www.merkle.com/papers/Thesis1979.pdf). This construction is totally insecure since the existent block cipher directly chained and it can be shown that it has $\mathcal{O}(2^{n/2})$ second-preimage resistance instead of $\mathcal{O}(2^{n})$.

We don't want [related key attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack) as exist in some of the block-ciphers like AES and DES. This doesn't create a problem for encryption since the keys are chosen uniform randomly, however, the related keys can be used to attack the hash function. This is discussed extensively by [Mannik and Preenel](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/909.pdf)

We want large inputs due to the collision attacks on the compression functions [[1]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/304) and therefore more rounds to process. So designers create a new block cipher for MD constructions instead of using existing ones. For SHA-1 it is called SHACAL and for SHA-2 it is called SHACAL-2.

The dividing value depends on the compression function, MD5, SHA-1, and SHA256 uses 512-bit message blocks, SHA512 is using 1024-bit message blocks. The messages are padded to be multiple of the block size with the message size is encoded at the end.

For example SHA-512 padding on [NIST FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf)

> Suppose that the length of the message, $M$, is $\ell$
> bits.  Append the bit `1` to the end of the message, followed by $k$ zero bits, where $k$ is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation
> $$\ell + 1 + k \equiv  896 \bmod 1024$$ Then append the 128-bit block that is equal to the number $\ell$ expressed using a binary representation

Formalize for arbitrary block size $b$ and $d$-bit encoded message size ( 64 for SHA-1 and SHA256, 128 for SHA512.

$$\ell + 1 + k \equiv  b-d \bmod b$$

So the design criteria are having a block cipher with many rounds, SHACAL has 80, SHA-256 has 64, and SHA512 has 80 rounds while keeping the round function simple.

And the block cipher is used as [Davies–Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer) to create a one-way compression function.

For example, the math for SHA256 is

- $\operatorname{Ch}(E,F,G) = (E \land F) \oplus (\neg E \land G)$
- $\operatorname{Ma}(A,B,C) = (A \land B) \oplus (A \land C) \oplus (B \land C)$
- $\Sigma_0(A) = (A\!\ggg\!2) \oplus (A\!\ggg\!13) \oplus (A\!\ggg\!22)$
- $\Sigma_1(E) = (E\!\ggg\!6) \oplus (E\!\ggg\!11) \oplus (E\!\ggg\!25)$

[image]

The bitwise rotation uses different constants for SHA-512. The given numbers are for SHA-256.
The red $\boxplus$ mean $ c = a + b \mod 2^{32}$, i.e. modulo addition.

As we can see, simple operations that CPUs can handle, light round function, with a little degraded unbalanced Feistel structure.

And we learned from the [Tiny Encryption algorithm](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=C08E8409ADF484095568965A1EBF3E5E?doi=10.1.1.45.281&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that, even simple rounds can be secure after 32 rounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nicely explained

Comment: Isn't it called SHACAL-2 for SHA-2?

Comment: @forest It was typo, yes it is called SHACAL-2, AFAIK, it is not as common as SHACAL-1. thanks.